# How to manage openUrl method inside called application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, query-string, openurl

I suppose that this is duplicate but I can not figure it out.

I have to call other app from my iOS app using `openUrl` method. After finishing its work the other app must return to my app using the same method. I figure out how to call the other App and its open my App too. My problem is how to intercept the return to my App. I need to check the value from query string.

I find that method `handleOpenURL` intercepts return and I can handle my query string.

And here I am stuck - how to use that info inside my ViewController? I set breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` but it was not hit. Which method I have to use?

**EDIT:**

My Code is (inside `AppDelegate`):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);

    return YES;
}

- (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:6];
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *val = [[elements objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [dict setObject:val forKey:key];
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Which works fine.

Inside my ViewController (VC):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

    // Instantiate App singleton
    singApp = [PESsingApplication sharedInstance];

    @try {

        // Localize resources using currently saved setting for language
        [self setLocalizedResources];

        // Init visual buttons
        [self baseInit];

        // Add code for keyboard management
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardHide:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        _screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        _screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [self throwUnknownException:exception];
    }
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

My url:

URL identifier: `xx.mydomain.MyUrlScheme`

URL shcemes: `MyUrlScheme`

I have breakpoints inside my `VC` (on each of the method shown above).

I use following string to call other app: `@"otherApp://openApp?param1=value1&callbackUrl=MyUrlScheme";`

They call me from the otherApp using `callbackUrl` param.

Comment: the callback is comes correctly , the above methods are works perfectly

Comment: So you mean that callback is not working correctly, @Anbu.Karthik?

Comment: check that your call back like inside  handleopenurl method just print NSlog(@"&@", url sourceapplication), u get anything or not

Comment: I got `MyApp://openMethod?param1=value1&param2=(null)` on the back call. I read both params inside `handleOpenURL` using `parseQueryString`, but the code did not stop on `viewDidLoad` inside my `VC`, @Anbu.Karthik.

Comment: then fine , add this string to NSUSerdefault and where you need this access it , simple , some times your sting has loose the memory also

Comment: now you reached the answer , i thing something is missing , if you do it it surely works

Comment: I am sorry, @Anbu.Karthik, I miss something. I don't understand what this all got with `NSUserDeafults` and which string to put inside. I can pass my `NSDictionary` which contains data from query string to my `ViewController` - I use singular and I will set that info there. My problem is that I can not intercept management inside my `ViewController` to react somehow. I suppose I need other method than `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `viewDidLoad` is not called perfectly try in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` method.

For example purpose:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);

// add dictionary to standardUserDefaults for saving purpose, like 

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"DicKey"]; 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// add code for navigation/present view controller

  UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
                                                         bundle: nil];
YourViewController *yourController = (YourViewController *)[mainStoryboard 
  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerID"];
self.window.rootViewController = yourController;

return YES;
}
```

for retrieve

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

NSMutableDictionary *mutableRetrievedDictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DicKey"] mutableCopy];

 // here parse the dictionary and do your work here, when your works is over 

 // remove the key of standardUserDefaults 

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"DicKey"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: No problem, but it not stop on any of those. I am missing something, but what?

Comment: Done. I still don't use `NSUserDefault`, because I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: @new2ios - your problem is over or else you need assistacne

Comment: Sorry, @Anbu.Karthik, I still have problem. I show you all of my code. When I return the breakpoints inside `VC` are not activated. I add comment about `NSUserDefault`, so you know that I don't implement it. The code did not stop on any of methods shown in my code above. I have return value, but I need to act according it. I need to raise Error or go to another page. May be I can call manually my `VC` from my `AppDelegate`, but I think tat this is not correct?

Comment: 10x, this is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your own custom URL, please look below

[**How to implement Custom URL Scheme**](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Defining your app's custom URL scheme is all done in the Info.plist file. Click on the last line in the file and then click the "+" sign off to the right to add a new line. Select URL Types for the new item. Once that's added, click the grey arrow next to "URL Types" to show "Item 0". Set your URL identifier to a unique string - something like com.yourcompany.yourappname.

After you've set the URL identifier, select that line and click the "+" sign again, and add a new item for URL Schemes. Then click the grey arrow next to "URL Schemes" to reveal "Item 0". Set the value for Item 0 to be your URL scheme name.

[image]

**Handling Custom URL Calls**

In order for your app to respond when it receives a custom URL call, you must implement the application:handleOpenURL method in the application delegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // your code
}
```

**Parsing the Custom URL**

There are several parts to a URL:

scheme://host/path?query

The parts to the URL can be retrieved through the NSURL object that is passed into the application:handleOpenURL method. If you have a fairly simple URL naming scheme and want to allow access to specific pages/keys, you can just use the host name:

Custom URL  Value of [url host]:

```
myapp://page1   page1
myapp://page2   page2
myapp://otherPage   otherPage
```

To pass data into your app, you'll want to use the query string. Here's a simple method for parsing the query string from the url:

```
- (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:6] autorelease];
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *val = [[elements objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [dict setObject:val forKey:key];
    }
    return dict;
}
```

**Testing The Custom URL**

You can easily test your URL scheme in the simulator. Just add a test button to one of your views, and implement the IBAction method for it as follows:

```
- (IBAction)getTest:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myappscheme://test_page/one?token=12345&domain=foo.com"]];
}
```

Then in your app delegate, implement the application:handleOpenURL method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
    return YES;
}
```

Finally if you are looking method to receive your data anywhere you can use this two scenario.
You can simple use [Local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html) or [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

**NSUserDefault**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleopenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
     [userDefaults synchronize];
     NSString *status = [defaults stringForKey:@"any status"];
}
```

**Local notification**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleopenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:VAL, @"value", nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but you did not read my question. I already do all that things. I parse the query string and I have it in the dictionary. My question is how to use that information inside my `ViewController` to which I was returned from the other App.

Comment: I read your question, Can you please explain what is man how to use information in my ViewController ?

Comment: Yes, @Grigori Jlavyan. I must receive status from other application. I got it. After that I need to show alert inside my `ViewController` from which I called other App. I put breakpoint on `viewDidLoad` method so I can rise alert or make other actions, but the breakpoint was not hit. So my question is which method should I use. Because I was return from the other App to the `ViewController` from which I call other app.

Comment: @GrigoriJlavyan - the questioner ased for call back methods , can you customize your ansewer

Comment: I have added some of method how you can receive any data

Answer (score 1):

Store the status from other app in `NSUserdefaults`, when the ViewController of your app launches fetch the status into a NSString from `NSUserdefaults` and rise it as an alert.

Call the `handleopenURL` in `appdelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleopenURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
     NSUserDefaults *defaults=[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
     [defaults synchronize];
     NSString *status = [defaults stringForKey:@"status string from other app"];
}
```